# which swing component i must use to apply different styles of text in a same field in java

Tags: java, swing, components, panel

i need to show a formatted text in a jframe, well is not that simple because i really lost in which component i must do this, i worked in visual time ago and there are a rich textbox that have all the function to do this work but in java, which is the similar swing component that can me allow to apply multiple fonts to specific portions of text, and if i can show the actual number of line and column in a label apart of where the cursor is in.

Comment: Did you have a look in the documentation of Swing? Another possibility would be to use an IDE and just make tests with the available text boxes.

Comment: Please define your problem in greater detail -- what **exactly** are you trying to achieve? You mention tabular data, and so I have to wonder if a JTable would be best. Or a JEditorPane or JTextPane -- again hard to tell based on what you've posted.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels is like the text editor in Netbeans IDE that apply format to a portion of text, what swing component allow me to do this? for example: public String example; -- the word public is going to be bold and blue, String with italic and example with green,  do you need more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> swing component that can me allow to apply multiple fonts to specific portions of text

Probably a JTextPane. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html).

> show the actual number of line and column in a label apart of where the cursor is in

You would need to use a `CaretListener`. You can then use the [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) to get the current line/column values. You can then format a string containing the values and set the text in a label on your status bar.